# Reference an arbitrary row and field in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there any form (data type, inherence..) of implement in postgresql something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE log (
    datareferenced table_row_column_reference,
    logged boolean
);
```

The referenced data may be any row field from the database. My objective is implement something like this without use Procedural Language or implement it in a higher layer, using only a relational approach and without modify the rest of the tables. Another feature may be referencial integrity, example:

```
-- Table foo (id,    field1,       field2, fieldn)
--           ('bar', '2014-01-01', 4.33,   Null)

-- Table log (datareferenced,                              logged)
--           ({table foo -> id:'bar' -> field2 } <=> 4.33, True)

DELETE FROM foo where id='bar';
-- as result, on cascade, deleted both rows.
```

I have an application build onto a MVC pattern. The logic is written in Python. The application is a management tool, very data intensive. My goal is implement a module that could store additional information per every data present in the DDBB. Per example, a client have a serie of attributes (name, address, phone, email ...) across multiple tables, and I want that the app could store metadata-like for every registry from all the DDBB. A metadata could be last modification, or a user flag, etc.

I have implemented the metadata model (in postgres), its mapping to objects and a parcial API. But the part left is the most important, the glue. My plan B is create that glue in the data mapping layer as a module. Something like this:

```
address= person.addresses[0]
address.saveMetadata('foo', 'bar')

-- in the superclass of Address 
def saveMetadata(self, code, value):
    self.mapper.metadata_adapter.save(self, code, value)

-- in the metadata adapter class:
def save(self, entity, code, value):
    sql = """update value=%s from metadata_values 
             where code=%s and idmetadata=
                      (select id from metadata_rels mr
                       where mr.schema=%s and mr.table=%s and 
                       mr.field=%s and mr.recordpk=%s)"""%         
                       (value, code,
                        self.class2data[entity.__class__]["schema"], 
                        self.class2data[entity.__class__]["table"],
                        self.class2data[entity.__class__]["field"],
                        entity.id)

    self.mapper.execute(sql)

def read(self, entity , code):
    sql = """select mv.value 
             from metadata_values mv
             join metadata_rels mr on mv.idmetadata=mr.id
             where mv.code=%s and mr.schema=%s and mr.table=%s and 
                   mr.field=%s and mr.recordpk=%s"""%         
                   (code,
                    self.class2data[entity.__class__]["schema"], 
                    self.class2data[entity.__class__]["table"],
                    self.class2data[entity.__class__]["field"],
                    entity.id )

    return self.mapper.execute(sql)
```

But it would add overhead between python and postgresql, complicate Python logic, and using PL and triggers may be very laborious and bug-prone. That is why i'm looking at doing the same at the DDBB level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's nothing like that in PostgreSQL.

You could build triggers yourself to do it, probably using a composite type. But you've said (for some reason) you don't want to use PL/PgSQL, so you've ruled that out. Getting RI triggers right is quite hard, though, and you must apply a trigger to the referencing *and* referenced ends.

Frankly, this seems like a square peg, round hole kind of problem. Are you sure PostgreSQL is the right choice for this application?

Describe your needs and goal in context. Why do you want this? What problem are you trying to solve? Maybe there's a better way to approach the same problem one step back...

Comment: So, you have a kind of key/value or EAV-like mapping and want to have the values have FK references to various different tables?

Comment: It's the best sum up.

Comment: @JorgeDíazDíaz Then the best you're going to get is hacks with user-defined triggers. Or you can use one join-table per relationship. It's not really something that's supported natively in the relational model.